# C# how to stop the program after a certain time?

Tags: c#, timeout, telnet

I have a big problem, but probably it's only big for me :). "terminal.Bind(client);" this line causes my program to hang if IP is bad. I want to stop this program after 5s working because if IP is wrong after 10s all program is hang.. :(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Rebex.TerminalEmulation;
using Rebex.Security;
using Rebex.Net;

namespace Routers_info_v._1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Telnet client = new Telnet("192.168.1.1");  
            VirtualTerminal terminal = new VirtualTerminal(80, 25);

            terminal.Bind(client);     

            terminal.SendToServer("pass\r");
            terminal.SendToServer("sys ver\r");

            TerminalState state;
            do
            {           
                state = terminal.Process(2000);
            } while (state == TerminalState.DataReceived);

            terminal.Save("terminal.txt", TerminalCaptureFormat.Text, TerminalCaptureOptions.DoNotHideCursor);
            terminal.Unbind();
            terminal.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to want to throw it in a thread and terminate the thread after a certain time.

Comment: Have you waited ~ 30 seconds? I think that's the general timeout period to establish a connection. In other words, your code may be blocking on attempting a connection to a bad IP. I think it should eventually return and probably cause an exception. Just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap the call in a try catch (assuming some exception is thrown):

```
try 
{
    terminal.Bind(client);     
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the goal of enforcing a timeout.

Comment: @RQDQ - Except it does.  If the ip address is not valid there is no reason to wait.  The current process only attempts to bind the ip address once, so waiting would be pointless.

Answer (score 2):

You could kick off the Bind in a thread, and start a timer, if the thread takes X seconds too long to complete, you could kill the thread, or your application, whichever you choose.

Comment: Hey!  I said almost the same thing in a comment :)  +1 anyway.

Comment: @DanAndrews - Then why didn't post it as an answer?

Comment: @DanAndrews, we must have posted at almost the exact time then, there was nothing on here when I posted

Comment: Yeah, we were like 10 seconds off or something.  @Oded, eh I thought it wasn't worthy of an answer, just a comment... I was wrong... I failed...

Answer (score 2):

You can use Task.Wait. Here is little simulation for an operation which will take 10 sec and you are waiting it for 5 sec to finish :)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
  class VirtualTerminal
  {
    public VirtualTerminal(int a, int b) { }
    public bool Bind() { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); return true; }
  }
  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      VirtualTerminal terminal = new VirtualTerminal(80, 25);

      Func<bool> func = () => terminal.Bind() ;
      Task<bool> task = new Task<bool>(func);
      task.Start();
      if (task.Wait(5*1000))
      {
        // you got connected
      }
      else
      {
        //failed to connect
      }


      Console.ReadLine();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i copy part of your code and it is working fine, but then i try to write some command like "terminal.SendToServer" or any with terminal.**** program say "does not contain definition"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put the network stuff into a second thread, which then may be aborted by the main thread.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadFunc);
        thread.Start();
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        while (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 5000 && thread.IsAlive)
            ;
        if (!thread.IsAlive) {
            thread.Abort();
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect");
        }
    }

    private static void threadFunc() {
        Telnet client = new Telnet("192.168.1.1");  
        VirtualTerminal terminal = new VirtualTerminal(80, 25);

        terminal.Bind(client);     
        // ...
        terminal.Dispose();
    }
}
```